# Should I repeat the trip to meet Terra with four non-magic users?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

After Terra had a lovely meetup with the Phantom Beast, followed by a lovely trip bouncing around the world everywhere, the other 6 playable characters agree to split up <s>because you can't have parties larger than four players</s> to go find her. For this I picked the Mechanic, the Samurai, the Monk and the Rune Knight. I figured that I should bring with me at least one magic user.

At the end of the trip, however, the group of four gains the ability to cast magic by touching each one piece of Magicite. This kind of a waste, because the Rune Knight already *can* do magic. Moreover, the fourth piece of Magicite came at a high price. Talk about unnecessary sacrifice.

Should I bother to replay this bit with four non-magic users? Should I actually make this a trip of three people, so that the unnecessary sacrifice doesn't happen to begin with?

Comment: not sure if you have played Final Fantasy 8 but the esper system in this game is pretty much exactly the same as the Guardian Force system in that game. Hope this helps to clear things up a bit.

Comment: @Ender This is the very first FF title I'm playing through.

Comment: @Ender I really wouldn't say they're that similar, the GF system is much more complicated and you can have multiples attached and there are passive abilities and yeah.  FF6 is actually a good first FF for badp because the Esper system is really simple (it's basically nothing but learning spells and minor stat adjustments), as opposed to the other games where the party members themselves are much less distinct.

Comment: @Sinrai I disagree about the guardian system being so different but thats ok. :) I do feel that FF6 is a great first FF however.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The new abilities will apply to any member of your party. Going forward, anyone on your team (including those you've yet to meet who will join in the future), will gain the ability to learn magic. To have them do so, simply have them equip a piece of Magicite - at the end of every battle from now on, in addition to Experience Points, you'll earn Magic Points, which go towards unlocking the spells associated with the particular Espers your party members have equipped.

To equip espers, open the menu, select `Skills`, one character, then pick `Esper`.

Each Esper has unique spells associated with it, so you'll want to move them around, and equip new ones as you acquire them in order to maximize the availability of important spells to all party members. Those characters with innate magic abilities (such as Celes), will also continue to learn specified new spells as they progress in levels. If you'd like to avoid redundancy here, you can consult a guide, but it's pretty hard to 'waste' MP in this manner, and by endgame, you'll have mastered all of the spells you need, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Do Magicite and Espers take up accessory slots?

Comment: @badp nope, they have their own dedicated slot. One per character. (They also affect stats, and each magicite has a summon associated with it, so there's a *bit* more to consider than which spells you want to learn.)

Comment: One other thing that maybe should be made explicit - this "sacrifice" happens regardless, you can't actually affect the outcome of this segment.  Also there is at least one character that can't learn spells from Espers (but can use them in another manner), and one other who can't use them at all (both of these are optional, though).

Answer (score 10):

Actually, you don't need to repeat the trip.  The misunderstanding is that the Magicite stays in the location you found it, and you have to keep going back to it.  That is false.  You take the Magicite with you, for use in your party(s).

So there's no sacrifice to be made; once you find Terra/Tina, you will gain a few pieces of Magicite, and any members of your party that don't have MP, all of sudden, do!  For those not currently in your party, they will have MP the next time you see them.

Note that this doesn't mean they'll have any spells; they won't.  They'll just have MP, and you have to equip the Espers to characters in order to get them to learn spells, so they can actually USE that MP.